# Error when convert datetime to milliseconds in qml blackberry

Tags: javascript, qml, blackberry-10

I got an error while i convert datetime to millisecond in qml.
I use javascript function but doesn't work.

here my code:

```
var data = new Date(Date.parse("2012-01-01", "yyyy-mm-dd")).getTime();
```

but doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = new Date(Date.parse("2012-01-01", "yyyy-MM-dd")).getTime();
```